# possible to design a more consistently performant data structure than .NET Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, dictionary, hashtable

The .NET `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`'s internal structure and process is a highly optimized design, as discussed by Simon Cooper in this excellent [blog post](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2011/09/16/103362.aspx).

The MSDN docs state that `Add(TKey,TValue)` is O(1) -- unless the Dictionary's element count is at capacity, necessitating that a dynamic resize operation first be performed, thus making Add() O(n) at these junctures.

As the Dictionary grows, resize operations become progressively more infrequent, and therefore it may be said that averaged over large n, Add() approaches O(1).

This is evidenced by Cooper in [this graph](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2011/10/21/103950.aspx) of total elapsed time for n/2 add operations as a function of n.

However, the *average worst case* performance of Add() is O(n).

My question : Is it possible to design a more consistently performant data structure than the .NET Dictionary ?

Specifically, I want *average worst case* performance of add, delete, retrieve operations to all be O(1).

Note that consistency of performance ( "big O" ) is the only relevant design criteria.  Memory utilization and absolute performance ( including degree of clustering & cache performance ) are not relevant design criteria.

Choosing an initial capacity much larger than anticipated needs is one option, but that is an initialization step, and I am looking for a data structure design.

Comment: Have you tried (no pun intended) `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: The only data structure that is *guaranteed* O(1) on *every* insertion is going to be a linked list. Do you have some exotic requirements that dictate this demand?

Comment: Pick an initial capacity >>> `n` ;-)

Comment: `SortedDictionary<TKey,Tvalue>` operations are always O(log(n)) and therefore worse than `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` which averages O(1).

Comment: @Jon I don't have any real world requirements, this is more of a theoretical question. My research so far is indicating that it is not possible to design a data structure with add, delete, retrieve *average worst case* performance all O(1).

Comment: @BaltoStar: If such a structure existed we 'd all be using it instead of bothering to choose. ;-)

Comment: You could add a `Sleep(5000000)` to every method call; then, amortized, every call will be `O(1)`...?

Comment: The comment of @pst might be intended to be funny, but I think this is the actual answer you are looking for. If you can't afford the resize of the internal array, pick an initial capacity that is big enough to fit all elements.

Comment: I realize this is an old question but this question shows, to me, a lack of real understanding of basic data structures stuff; maybe check out a textbook on algorithms and data structures to understand why this is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Have you simply tried creating a dictionary with a big enough size?

Generic O(1) is basically an array. Access via index. Or hierarchical arrays (4 byte key, array pointing to aray pointing to array pointing to array pretty much, to save space).

Anythig else - no, sorry.

Lots of high performance stuff uses preallocated arrays.

Comment: Pre-allocating `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` to size far greater than anticipated need is one solution I thought of.  But what I am after is actually a data structure *design* that has add, retrieve, delete *average worst case* performance all O(1).

Comment: As I said - that is an array. Per definition. Index based access with linear index to position transaltion is about the onely thing I know that gives you total O(1) - without the ability to insert / remove items and have the others change position.